# Woocoommerce deleting users automatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordprss website and my users are always dissapearing. That's a big problem because my website has thousands of users and if I don't do backups daily I'll loose it all.

I've googled this problem and I cannot find a solution to this.

Looking into the Scheduled Actions I've found a "wc-admin_delete_user_customers", I belive that this is deleting my users. I've looked into woocommerce settings and I cannot find any place that I can disable this setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in woocommerce setting

woocommerce => configure => Account and privacy => personal information
Retain inactive accounts N/A